# Format array for batch api call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have an array with this format:

`var customerList = [{'email: ex@mail.com', 'name': 'John'}, {...}, {...}]`

However I need to format a batch api call for the following format for each of the objects in the array:

```
api.post('/:batch_endpoint'), {
   0: {url: '/:endpoint', data: {email: customerList[0].email}}, 
   1: {...},
   2: {...},
}
```

So essentially I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically fill the records for the api call from that array or another list. So far I've tried to use `Object.assign()` but not sure if this is the right way forward:

`var customerObject =  Object.assign({}, customerList)` outputs:

```
{
  '0': {
   email: 'ex@mail.com',
   '...',
 },
  1: {...}
}
```

Beyond this point I'm not sure how I can format this api call properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're asking how to send batch updates as a 1st index-based array (instead of 0th index-based) you have at least a couple of options:

Option 1: Use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to add one to the key:

```js
customerList.reduce((acc, data, idx) => ({
  ...acc,
  [parseInt(idx) + 1]: {
    url: "/:endpoint",
    data
  }
}), [])
```

Option 2: Use the [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method to add a "garbage" value to the `0th` index:

```js
// Convert the values in the array into the shape you want to send
customerList.map(data => ({ url: "/:endpoint", data }))

// Insert garbage value at index 0
customerList.unshift(0)
```

Option 3: Update your API to support `0th` indexed-arrays if you plan on sending data frequently. IMO, the above two solutions are a hack and less than ideal. However, this may not be possible in your situation.

Comment: Sorry I should have checked earlier, it does work on 0-index arrays. Would the solution be to not use reduce?

Comment: Are you asking how to format the data in `customerList` like this? `{url: '/:endpoint', data: {email: customerList[0].email}}`

Comment: Sorry yes I figured it out using your second solution. Thanks a lot!